# SSRS dropdown with progressive search

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to make a dropdown in SSRS limit what is shown as a value is typed. As it currently is it just goes to the first item starting with the letter, but in a big list, this still means a lot of scrolling to get to the desired value. This specific report is on SQL Server 2019, but if there is a way to do it for 2016 as well that would be nice to update some of the reports on older servers

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this directly. However, you can do this with some compromise.

Let's say I have a long list of customers that I want to filter.

I create a dataset (`dsCustomers`) with a dataset query something like

```
SELECT * FROM customers
```

I have a parameter which uses this dataset as it's list of available values called `pCustomer`

If I want to be able to filter this list I would add a new parameter called, say, `pCustSearch`. This will be a simple parameter with no associated dataset. You can optionally allow NULL values.

Now I can change the dataset query for `dsCustomers` to be

```
SELECT * 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE (Customername like '%' + @pCustSearch + '%'
           OR 
           @pCustSearch ISNULL)
```

NOTE: The pCustSearch parameter must be the first parameter (or at least before the pCustomer parameter)

Once you have filled in the search parameter and tab to the main customer drop down, it should filter the values that match what you have typed.