# Use Search Function instead of using dropdownlist in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Goal:
Possible to use use search function instead of using dropdownlist in Reporting services.

Problem:
Today, the dropdownlist consist of 2500 rows in relation to parameter for prompt.

You might understand that it is not userfriendly to review and locate a specific information from the dropdownlist by using scroll.

Does SSRS provide a function that you can write in a textbox something similiar and it will display the result based on the data from dropdownlist?
In other words, you write something and a result will display instead of reviewing the dropdownlist.

Info:
*This is related to reporting services that is part of SQL server

Thank you!

[image: This is a sample of drowpdownlist for prompt]

This picture is a sample of dropdownlist.

Comment: AFAIK the best you can do is add a free text box where the user can enter some text, which is then used in the where clause for the query to populate your dropdownlist.

Comment: Maybe another free form text parameter that the actual drop down parameter's query references? Then add a WHERE to your parameter's query `WHERE Country LIKE '%' + @PARAMETER + '%' or @PARAMETER IS NULL. `

Comment: As Dale and Hannover have suggested... have a look at one of my old answers that explain how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518598/ssrs-dropdown-with-progressive-search