# Filtering results of report parameter values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

In report designer I have a parameter which its values come from another dataset.
The parameter values dataset consists of over 5000 rows. So I want to know how to I can enable filtering on this set.

Comment: Please add more information, how would you like to filter the parameter values? There are a few way of doing this but without knowing more it's hard to know what method will work. Here's my answer to a similar question that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518598/ssrs-dropdown-with-progressive-search/65523232#65523232

Comment: My report shows list of proposals which linked with customers. report also contains a paramter to filter the proposals per customer; this params's values comes from database query to make users able to select customers from dropdown, and here it is the problem, customers query will fetch more than 5000 records.

Comment: Now I am using another parameter to filter customers list, but I am looking for some way more user friendly.